# insertAt() raises InvalidValueError

Tags: javascript, latitude-longitude, google-polyline

I have a google maps polyline that when clicked on, adds a point where clicked.  After finding the index at which to add, I insert the point with:

`path.insertAt(minIndex+1,event.latLng);`

This is raising the error:

"Uncaught InvalidValueError: in property path: fewer than 2 LatLngs"

Any idea where this is coming from or how it can be avoided?  The `path` comes from `path=polyObj.getPath()` and has 13 points in the example I have been trying.  The `event` is passed from a mouse click event.  Commenting out this line removes any errors, so the rest of the code is working fine.